# How would I make sure the width is 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of variable images that will display randomly when the page is loaded. My question is how would I make sure the width of any of those variable images is 100% width of the window, so that when an image is displayed it is able to be resized, therefore responsive. I would like to target the Javascript/Jquery below if possible. Also, is there a way to not append to the div class of?

-------> Javascript

```
<div class="box">
<!------------Random Image script   start  below------------>
<div id="main-image"><script type="text/javascript">
var images = ['typewriter.jpg','tygsdfgr.jpg', 'gdadfa.jpg', 'fasdfd.jpg'];
$('.box').css({'background-image': 'url(images/cover-images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
$('<img src="images/cover-images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('.box');
</script></div>
<!------------Random Image script   END------------>
</div>
```

--------->CSS

```
#main-image {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle link ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a2XY7/2/

Comment: Are you trying to get the background-image in the `<div class="box">` to be 100% of the window size, or the `<img>` to be 100% of the window size? Or both?

Comment: @chowey I'm trying to get the image that is within the unused 'box' div to resize 100% of the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your image tag fill the entire window, just use a bit of css:

```
#main-image img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You should NOT be doing a `background-image` on the `<div class="box">` at the same time. Just the image tag is enough.

---

Alternatively, you could use ONLY a `background-image` and use `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain`, but this is not supported in some older browsers. It also requires javascript to calculate which height to use. Since this is more complicated and less supported, I do not recommend this. I recommend you just use an `<img>` tag as above.

Comment: Also here is a fiddle to show some different sized images filling the window. http://jsfiddle.net/LQST2/

Comment: Thanks, that is ultimately what I ended up doing. First I did a straight img tag in css by itself, then what you have above. Either way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-image {
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Make sure whatever area you want it to fill has a position of `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` as well or it'll propagate up until it finds something to relate to.  In other words - `<div class="box">` needs to be one of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if width of the image is equal to the width of the window then do the following:

Let the image id be `id=img` then condition will be->

`if($('#img').width()==$(window).width()){}`

To get image width simly right->

`var image=$('#img').width();`

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is not setting the width of the image element. It's setting the width of the container div. Also you are applying the image as a CSS background. The only way to make a CSS background scale to the full width of the element would be to use the repeat attribute, which would cause it to tile.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do is a good idea. If the parent container is much bigger than the image file, re-sizing the image to the dimensions of the parent container will make the image appear very pixelated.

That being said, you could write a resizeImage() method which gets the width and height of the parent container and sets the the dimensions of the image accordingly. You can use jQuery .width() and .height() to get the parent container dimensions. Append the image to the parent container. Use it as an inline image. Do not apply it as a CSS background. Call resizeImage() after the image has been appended. Bind a handler function to the $(window).resize() event which calls resizeImage(). This way when the browser window is re-sized the image will adjust accordingly.